# Is there a name for this constant associated to smooth maps between spheres? (not degree)

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, homotopy-theory, de-rham-cohomology

Consider the following constant associated to smooth maps $F: S^{2n-1} \to S^n$ for $n \geq 2$:

Let $\omega \in \Omega^n(S^n)$ be a volume form with $\int_{S^n} \omega = 1$. Then there exists $\eta \in \Omega^{n-1}\left( S^{2n-1} \right)$ with $d\eta = F^*\omega$; define
$$ h(F) = \int_{S^{2n-1}} \eta \wedge d\eta. $$

On a recent exam, I was given this definition and asked to show it is independent of choices of $\omega$ and $\eta$, invariant under smooth homotopy, and satisfies $h(F) = 0$ for odd $n$.

Is there a name for this constant? Does it have any important properties or show up in any interesting places?

Thanks!

Comment: Note that $\mathrm{d}(\eta\wedge \eta) = \mathrm{d}\eta\wedge \eta + (-1)^{n-1}\eta\wedge\mathrm{d}\eta$. As $(n-1)n$ is always even, $\mathrm{d}\eta\wedge \eta = \eta \wedge \mathrm{d}\eta$. Look at Stokes theorem when $n$ is odd.

Comment: This should be an incarnation of the [Hopf invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_invariant), though off the top of my head I don't recall how to prove the equivalence with the usual definition.

Comment: I may expand this into an answer later, but I recently learned that it also measures the 3-skeleton obstruction to homotopy between 2-plane fields over a 3-manifold.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Eric says, this integral equals the **[Hopf Invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_invariant)**. This equality was first proven by Whitehead in

*Whitehead, J. H. C.*, [**An expression of Hopf’s invariant as an integral**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1073/pnas.33.5.117), Proc. Natl. Acad. Sci. USA 33, 117-123 (1947). [ZBL0030.07902](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0030.07902).

when $n=2$ and then by Whitney in full generality; see sections 31, 33 in Chapter IV of

*Whitney, Hassler*, Geometric integration theory, Princeton Mathematical Series. Princeton, N. J.: Princeton University Press; London: Oxford University Press. XV, 387 p. (1957). [ZBL0083.28204](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0083.28204).

Comment: There is also an earlier proof in J.H.C. Whitehead, "An Expression of Hopf's Invariant as an Integral", PNAS, vol. 33, no. 5 (1947), for the special case when $n = 2$.

Comment: @JHF: Right, I should have mentioned this.